# Использовать векторные карты Земли в OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, svg, карты

В проекте есть OpenGL-виджет, который рисует Землю в 3D и плоскую карту. Карта сейчас - это картинка в формате *.jpg. Для Земли в 3D рисуется сфера, на которую накладывается текстура-картинка. Нужно, чтобы в качестве текстуры использовалась векторная картинка. И при увеличении масштаба Земля детализировалась.(Появлялись границы государств и их столицы).
Как это сделать? С чего начать?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще было бы замечательно немного конкретизировать задачу, а именно:

1. Если карта очертаний географических объектов - векторная, то она должна быть задана в виде наборов вершин и треугольников (либо только вершин, в виде замкнутых многоугольников, которые придется потом триангулировать). Так ли это?
2. Предполагается ли, что виджет умеет "смотреть" под любым углом, или только вертикально вниз, к центру планеты? От этого зависит способ изменения LOD.

Пока скажу только вот что. Гугл и Яндекс уже имеют у себя готовые варианты детализации векторных данных о географических объектах для всех вариантов масштаба, и клиенту посылают готовые растровые тайлы, которые уже используются для отрисовки, и клиент отдает серверу уровень масштаба и координаты, а тот уже отдает соответствующие этому масштабу тайлы с нужным уровнем детализации. По крайней мере раньше так было. Сейчас уже по-другому.

Этот вариант плох тем, что из-за хранения всех-всех уровней детализации в растре, для реализации такой модели нужен очень большой объем данных.

Второй вариант, более приемлемый с точки зрения объема данных - использовать векторные данные об очертаниях географических объектов, потому что у них нет нужды подгонять уровень детализации.

В зависимости от того, как именно заданы эти очертания, вам придется выполнять разные математические действия для того, чтобы спроецировать координаты имеющихся, вероятно, в двумерной проекции вершин на сферу. В этом могут помочь полярные координаты, где широта и долгота будут соответствовать двумерным координатам исходных данных.

В зависимости от объема данных о географии, можно отделить уровни детализации, раскидав их по разным вершинным буферам (материки отдельно, реки отдельно, города и дороги, если такие есть, отдельно), при этом еще отсортировав индексы по долготе, например, чтобы не рисовать то, что не видно, и не заставлять видеокарту тестировать видимость безумного количества треугольников, когда масштаб максимальный, просто сместив начальный индекс в функции glDrawIndexed на индекс, соответствующий начальным координатам.

Пока это все, что можно сказать, уточняйте задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Растеризовать наблюдаемую на Земле область векторного изображения и выводить ее стандартными текстурами. Динамически обновляя и подменяя область и уровни детализации.

Разбить Землю на части (например треугольники), каждому треугольнику сопоставлять область векторного изображения и дочерние трейгольники с большей детализацией. При отрисовке определять какие треугольники видно и с какой детализацией, соответственно им генерировать текстуры нужной детализиции.